# Why Kotlin function parameter names break the method call?

Tags: kotlin

Wonder what is wrong with specifying Kotlin function parameter name when calling a function. In some situation it won't work and I don't know how to fix it.

For example, this code works fine without specifying the parameters' names:

```
assertEquals(
    FakeDataSource.photosList,
    repository.getMarsPhotos(),
)
```

But the same code with parameters name give me a compiler error:

```
assertEquals(
    expected = FakeDataSource.photosList,
    actual = repository.getMarsPhotos(),
)
```

[image]

Comment: Because you're calling a java function, and named parameters are not supported for java interop because argument names in class files are optional and not enabled by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html#named-arguments) tells us this:

> When calling Java functions on the JVM, you can't use the named argument syntax because Java bytecode does not always preserve the names of function parameters.

You are calling a JUnit method there, written in Java.